# Shape of passed values when applying pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, train-test-split

I want to create a dataframe after splitting the dataset. But i got the following error ;

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (159886, 291), indices imply
> (291, 291)

My code;

```
X=df.drop("target",axis=1)
y=df["target"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, i_train, i_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

x_df = pd.DataFrame(X[i_train], df.columns[:-1].to_list())
```

I am using X[i_train] instead of X_train because they are not the same (i_train) .

How can avoid this problem?

Comment: Why are you splitting it into 6 parts? `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, i_train, i_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)`. You should only have `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test` on the left side.

Comment: since you passed 2 arrays to `train_test_split`, it returns a list of 4 arrays.

Comment: Apart from the above comments, the second argument you pass to `pd.DataFrame`, i.e., `df.columns[:-1].to_list()` is interpreted as *index* as you passed it positionally. You *probably* meant it to be the columns of the new frame so please make it explicit as `x_df = pd.DataFrame(X[i_train], columns=df.columns[:-1].to_list())` by the keyword argument.

Comment: By the way, due to the above comments, you first get *ValueError: not enough values to unpack* before you get that error so your example is misconstructed.